# Testing functions that throw exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, error-handling

I'm using [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) and I'm trying to test a couple of functions. My functions throw errors and validate objects. I like throwing errors because then later my promises can catch them. I'm trying to run simple tests and establishing the  `data` argument in all the scenarios to hit each error in the stack. How can I test this function without putting it in a `try / catch` every time? I see there's two functions in the API [`t.throws()`](https://github.com/substack/tape#tthrowsfn-expected-msg) and [`t.doesNotThrow()`](https://github.com/substack/tape#tdoesnotthrowfn-expected-msg), I've tried them both and even added the extra params like `t.throws(myFunc({}), Error, "no data")` but nothing seems to work as expected.

```
var test = require('tape')
var _ = require('underscore')

function myFunction(data){
  if(!data) throw new Error("no data")
  if(_.size(data) == 0) throw new Error("data is empty")
  if(!data.date) throw new Error("no data date")
  if(!data.messages.length == 0) throw new Error("no messages")
  data.cake = "is a lie"
  return data
}

test("my function", function(t){
  t.throws(myFunction({}))
  t.end()
}
```

I have no loyalty to tape, and I have no clue what I'm doing. I just want to simply test functions synchronous that throw exceptions, without a ton of overhead. So if there's a better unit-testing framework for this use case I'd be glad to use it. If tape has this ability I'd love to use it.

**Is this how it should be done?**

```
test("my function", function(t){
  try{
    myFunction({})
    t.fail()
  }catch(e){
    t.pass(e.message)
  }
  t.end()
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems I cant call the function within the argument of `t.throws` because it throws the error, duh. I believe this is the correct usage.

```
t.throws(function(){
  myFunction({})
})
```

Comment: Or `t.throws(myFunction.bind(null, {}), 'should throw an exception')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bind as suggested in the comment above, u could use the arrow function like this:

`t.throws(() => myFunction({}), 'should throw an exception')`